# Post request in swift with encodable

Tags: ios, swift, post, nsjsonserialization, encodable

I want to create a post request in swift but i got confused in `Encodable` protocols. and how to create them.

below is the data that i want to post :

```
{
answers: [{
            "time": 1,
            "score": 20,
            "status": true,
            "answer": 456
 }],
challenge_date": "2019-03-13"  
}
```

How can i post it with `Encodable` or `JSONSerialization`?

Comment: **Q1.** What does your `POST` request look like? **Q2.** Does this have to be a json string, can't you just make it a `[String:Any]` object? **Q3.** Do you have a `Codable` model for this?

Comment: Also, your json structure is invalid. The root object is a dictionary but the array is not associated with any key name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This JSON is wrong. You JSON must be valid. In order to make above JSON valid we need to set array with a key.

#### Wrong

```
{
 [{
            "time": 1,
            "score": 20,
            "status": true,
            "answer": 456
 }],
challenge_date": "2019-03-13"  
}
```

#### Correct

```
{
    "array": [{
                "time": 1,
                "score": 20,
                "status": true,
                "answer": 456
     }],
    "challenge_date": "2019-03-13"  
}
```

Swift models for above JSON is this.

```
struct YourJSONModel: Codable {
    var challenge_date: String
    var array: Array<ResultModel>
}
struct ResultModel: Codable {
    var time: Int
    var score: Int
    var status: Bool
    var answer: Int
}

var result = ResultModel()
result.time = 10
result.score = 30
result.status = true
result.answer = 250


var jsonModel = YourJSONModel()
jsonModel.array = [result]
jsonModel.challenge_date = "2019-03-13"
```

Convert above model to json data to post. Use below code.

```
let jsonData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(jsonModel)

var request = URLRequest(url: yourApiUrl)
request.httpBody = jsonData
request.httpMethod = "POST"

Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print(response)                    
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Alamofire and pass the parameter as a dictionary with `encoding: JSONEncoding.default`, See the following code.

```
    Alamofire.request(urlString!, method: .post, parameters: parameter, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print(response)                    
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
    }
```

Comment: what is `Parameter` here? can you show it with my data?

Comment: the parameter is just passed your [String:Any] type dictionary, Which is you want to pass in API Call.